# How to enable publishing feature using CSOM?

Tags: publishing-site, client-object-model

How to enable site collection publishing infrastructure and site publishing features using CSOM?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How to activate feature via Managed Client Object Model:

```
public void ActivateFeature(string webFullUrl,Guid featureId,bool force,FeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)
{
    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webFullUrl))
    {
       var features = ctx.Web.Features;
       ctx.Load(features);
       ctx.ExecuteQuery();

       features.Add(featureId, force, featdefScope);
       ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

### About feature activation via CSOM

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.featurecollection.add(v=office.15).aspx) the `FeatureCollection.Add`  method has the following signature

```
public Feature Add(
    Guid featureId,
    bool force,
    FeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope
)
```

which is intended for adding the feature to the collection of activated features and returns the added feature

Parameter [FeatureDefinitionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.featuredefinitionscope%28v=office.14%29.aspx)  is used for specifying the feature scope for a feature definition.
At the same time the documentation says:

> It must have the value of `FeatureDefinitionScope.Site` or
>   `FeatureDefinitionScope.Farm`

It basically means that the method `FeatureCollection.Add` does not accept `FeatureDefinitionScope.Web` value for `featdefScope`  and therefore feature  activation with **Web scope** is not supported in CSOM.

---

In your case one of the features is Web scoped

> PublishingWeb SharePoint Server
>   Publishing    94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb    Web

and therefore it could **not** be activated via CSOM since `FeatureDefinitionScope.Web` is not supported

P.S. This is not correct statement, see the update section below.

**Update**

In order to activate **Web** level feature specify `FeatureDefinitionScope.None`, the following example demonstrates how to activate `SharePoint Server Publishing (Web)` feature:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

    var featureId = new Guid("94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb");
    var features = ctx.Web.Features;
    features.Add(featureId, true, FeatureDefinitionScope.None);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

> Has been verified in SharePoint CSOM v16.

---

How to verify feature scope

```
$feature = get-spfeature featureId
if ($feature -eq $null -or $feature -eq "") {
    echo "no feature found with id"
} else {
  echo ("feature found. Scope is  " + $feature.Scope)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this method:

```
function ActivateFeature(featureGuid)
{
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var site = clientContext.get_site();
var guid = new SP.Guid('{'+featureGuid+'}');

var featDef = site.get_features().add(guid, false, SP.FeatureDefinitionScope.site);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnFail));
}

function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
    alert('Success!');
}

function OnFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Fail: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/09/activate-feature-with-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: this is JSOM not CSOM

Answer (score 0):

Specifying FeatureDefinitionScope.Farm as the FeatureDefinitionScope scoped worked for me. I have tried both Web and Site scopes but they did not work. I have succesfully activated publishing feature after web provisioned event from a remote event receiver using csom

ref:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d063e579-8cbe-4522-8c1e-eec83329a12b/how-to-activate-a-feature-from-client-om?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious